# Cassandra token assignment in a cluster

Tags: cassandra, database, nosql

I'm having a confusion over the token assignment on Cassandra node.

so assume i have 3 node cluster and there is only one token assigned to each node.

for an example the token range is 10 and each node has tokens like these ..

```
node1 -> 3,     
node2 -> 4,      
node3 -> 5,
```

so what happen if partitioner produce token of 7 for a particular data.where does that data go ???

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Data in Cassandra is managed as part of a token *ring*. Token values will wrap around at the end, so that in your example node1 will be responsible for ranges 6-3.